# Verifying solidity contract on polygonscan

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, nft

I created a Solidity Contract. What information should go in "Enter the Solidity Contract Code below?"

Below I am also listing the solidity code I used.

I tried putting the code in directly and the website errors out on me.

I am also attaching the link to the contract on polygonscan
https://polygonscan.com/token/0xd1a8ee4c74e0153aa1282967336b4a35f60a8dab

[image]
[image]

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract EmbassyBuddhas is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;
    uint256 public presaleCost = 0.03 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 20;
    bool public paused = false;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
    mapping(address => bool) public presaleWallets;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        mint(msg.sender, 20);
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // public
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(!paused);
        require(_mintAmount > 0);
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            if (whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
                if (presaleWallets[msg.sender] != true) {
                    //general public
                    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
                } else {
                    //presale
                    require(msg.value >= presaleCost * _mintAmount);
                }
            }
        }

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
        }
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setPresaleCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        presaleCost = _newCost;
    }

    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
        paused = _state;
    }

    function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = true;
    }

    function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = false;
    }

    function addPresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = true;
    }

    function add100PresaleUsers(address[100] memory _users) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            presaleWallets[_users[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removePresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = false;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value: address(this).balance
        }("");
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are having problems verifying contract code is because in your contract you are importing code from others contract, but you are not pasting that code there, I'll recommend you to check how to "flatten" a contract in the tool you are using and paste the flattened contract there

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do that in Remix?

Comment: i haven't try to do it in remix, but you can try this https://medium.com/remix-ide/verify-contracts-on-remix-with-sourcify-2912004d9c84, if not try with hardhat

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use frameworks such as [truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) and [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) to verify the contract because it will help you to make it easy.

So you can read more details How to verify contract on this [link](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html)